# Code Igniter - Get Before Last URI Segment

Tags: codeigniter, uri, segment

I found on stackOverflow that I get the last segment can be found like this:

```
end($this->uri->segment_array());
```

**There is a work around from the statement above to get the before last segment?**

I'm not asking about

```
$this->uri->uri_to_assoc(n)
```

or

```
$this->uri->segment(n)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Both answers are working but I like more @Jordan answer. My choice! Thank you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the segment before.

```
$secondLastKey = count($this->uri->segment_array())-1;
$this->uri->segment($secondLastKey);
```

Comment: Actually, I need only the last and the before last. I passed vars from jQuery in the URL. Thanks.

Comment: Well the before last is given here. The last is given by the end() function you described. merge the two together with the concatenation operator (.) if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

```
$segs = $this->uri->segment_array();
$number = count($segs)-2;
echo $segs[$number];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$last = $this->uri->segment($this->uri->total_segments());
$beforelast = $this->uri->segment($last--);
```